# Can't escape double quotes in RegularExpression using named parameters. C#

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc

I have the following RegEx:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[^,']+$|^$", ErrorMessageResourceName = "AlphaNumeric", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.LocalizedStrings))]
```

This currently allows all characters except a , and a '. However I also need to exclude " but so far have not been able to, as it ends the initial double quote after the @ sign. I've searched Google for help but none of the answers seem to relate to what I'm doing, or seem to work for me.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

EDIT - Thanks to everyone for their help, using the unicode equivalent worked for me. \u0022
        See Anirudh's answer

Comment: Have you tried the non "@"-prefixed string, then escaping the double-quote normally, eg \"?

Comment: Escape `"` like `""` for verbatim literals

Comment: Hi, I have tried both ways but it still doesn't work. Note that both the , and ' are caught ok. I've tried both:
[RegularExpression("^[^,'\"]+$|^$",...
[RegularExpression(@"^[^,'""]+$|^$",...

Please let me know if I've done it wrong

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to escape `"`

With verbatim string's you need to escape `"` as `""`

If that doesn't work use `\u0022` which is unicode equivalent of `"` i.e `@"^[^,'\u0022]+$|^$"`